# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes)

Tags: php

I am trying to insert some serial numbers into a database.  I have defined the range for this and I made a function that returns the last record and increments it if I have already inserted the related serial number.  However, I'm getting an error in the code when I attempt to increment the result.  It works fine if I hardcode it but not when I attempt to increment the value:

```
$batch = $_POST['batch'];
$serial=11111111;
if(array_key_exists('batch',$_POST)){
    $query="select serial from serials where serial like";
    $query.="'".$_POST['batch']."%'";
    $query.='order by serial DESC limit 0,1';
    $rs=mysql_query($query);
    while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
        $a =($row[serial]);
        $a = substr($a,0,2);// substring to match the string
        if($a == $batch){
        $a2 =($row[serial]);
        $a2 = substr($a2,2,-1);//substring to get the serial
        $serial =$a2;
        }
        else
        {
        $serial=11111111;
        };
    }
}
function createColumnsArray($end_column, $first_letters = ''){
    $columns = array();
    $length = strlen($v);
    $letters = range($serial,11111999); //(12847017, 12847027);
    foreach ($letters as $letter){
        $column = $first_letters.$_POST['batch'].$letter.'Z';
        $columns[].=$column;
        if ($column == $end_column)
        return $columns;
    }
    foreach ($columns as $column){
        if (!in_array($end_column, $columns) && strlen($column) < $length) {
        $new_columns = createColumnsArray($end_column, $column);
        // Merge the new columns which were created with the final columns array.
        $columns = array_merge($columns, $new_columns);
        }
    }
return $columns;
}
```

Comment: Have a look on `Related` right of your question.

Comment: increase the memory size you have allocated to PHP.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a kind of recursion (calling `createColumnsArray` inside `createColumnsArray`) and it's infinite

Comment: i have tried ini_set('memory_limit','128M'); but getting same error;

Comment: if i hardcode the value as  range(11111111,11111999); then it works fine but i need to increment next time the number from db.

Comment: @BhavikShah While you can work around this error by increasing memory limit does not mean that you should be doing it all the time. E.g.: If I had to process large images, increasing memory limit would be valid. But when I don't do anything _special_ like that, this means that I have potential buggy code somewhere in my whole script. So I'd better debug code and fix this at software level, so I am able to avoid problems in future. In given question, OP has recursive call.

Comment: @user2042007 why do you not pass `$serial` as an argument of your function?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your memory limit try

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

134217728 bytes = 128 MB

Or consider rewriting an efficient code so that it would consume less memory..

Comment: I'd exchange priorities here.

Comment: its not working does any method to see how much memory is being consumed bu php?

Comment: @user2042007 [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Comment: @user2042007 then probably the while loop is running infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try...
Allowed memory size maximum. Put the code top of the file
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```